# How many 7-person committees can be formed out of a class of 20 students?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this question!! it's really bugging me

Comment: You know what are permutations and combinations?

Comment: That's the basic choose function: $\binom{20}{7}$. Look up the concept and see how it (perfectly!) applies to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a [binomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html):

$$\binom{20}{7}=\frac{20!}{7!(20-7)!}=77520,$$

pronounced "$20$ choose $7$".